# Creating query to return Parameter and Parameter values in single result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, transpose

How do I consolidate/transpose the following tables into one record per customer but having the parameters as columns?

4 tables:

- Company
- Attribute
- Company_Attribute
- Company_Attribute_Values

*Source Tables:*

[image: Source Tables]

*Desired Output:*

[image: Output looking for]

Comment: Have you seen pivot [**SAMPLES**](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: For you case just join all 4 tables together and then pivot that result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like have two questions  Join the tables and Create the [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

I will help you with the join

```
SELECT C.Name, A.Title, CAV.Value
FROM Company C
JOIN Company_Attribute_Values CAV
  ON C.id = CAV.company_id
JOIN Attribute A
  ON CAV.attribute_id = A.id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/214de/1)**

```
|     Name |          Title |    Value |
|----------|----------------|----------|
| ABC Corp |       Currency |      USD |
| ABC Corp |         Reg No |   Reg123 |
| ABC Corp |         Vat No |  Vat5153 |
| ABC Corp | AccountManager | Mr J Doe |
| XYZ Corp |       Currency |      EUR |
| XYZ Corp |         Vat No |   VAT654 |
|     ACME |       Currency |      EUR |
|     ACME |         Reg No |   Reg567 |
|     ACME |         Vat No |   Vat213 |
```

btw doesnt make sense you have two table for store same data. `Company_Attribute` is the same table as `Company_Attribute_Values` less one field. So just remove the first one.

**[PIVOT part](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/214de/3)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT C.Name, A.Title, CAV.Value
    FROM Company C
    JOIN Company_Attribute_Values CAV
      ON C.id = CAV.company_id
    JOIN Attribute A
      ON CAV.attribute_id = A.id
)
SELECT name, 
    [Currency], [Reg No], [Vat No], [AccountManager]
FROM
    cte
PIVOT
(
MAX([Value])
FOR Title IN ([Currency], [Reg No], [Vat No], [AccountManager])
) AS PivotTable;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|     name | Currency | Reg No |  Vat No | AccountManager |
|----------|----------|--------|---------|----------------|
| ABC Corp |      USD | Reg123 | Vat5153 |       Mr J Doe |
|     ACME |      EUR | Reg567 |  Vat213 |         (null) |
| XYZ Corp |      EUR | (null) |  VAT654 |         (null) |
```

Comment: Thanx for the response, can i ask 1 more thing. The Attribute table is Dynamic, whereby new parameters can be added within the program. So i need a dynamic list of parameter values. The same tables was just a to illustrate the situation, actual tables are bit more complex.

Comment: You can do the same with dynamic pivot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query